# radio buttons showing only first option correct and the others showing all wrong data in android

Tags: android, radio-button

In my questions answers small game i am showing questions and answers from the database file.
question is in text view and answers are in radiobuttons.no the data is showing accurately the way i wanted but when i am selecting the data only the first option of the radio button is selecting as correct ansnwer only if it is the correct answer.my code in mainactivity is as follows `showQuestion = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvQuestions);
        showAnswer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvShowAnswer);

```
    radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
     r0 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio0);
    r1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio1);
    r2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio2);
    r3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio3);
    bsubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bsubmit);
    bsubmit.setOnClickListener(this);

              String shoow = myDb.makeatext(levels, Qno);
    String showextra1 = myDb.makeExtra1(levels, Qno);
    String showextra2 = myDb.makeExtra2(levels, Qno);
    String showextra3 = myDb.makeExtra3(levels, Qno);
    String showextra4 = myDb.makeExtra4(levels, Qno);

    // String showextra4 =myDb.makeanswers(levels, Qno);

    showQuestion.setText(shoow);
    r0.setText(showextra1);

    r1.setText(showextra2);

    r2.setText(showextra3);

    r3.setText(showextra4);
```

and in the onclick() method trying to check the data but it is showing only first radio button answer as correct if the data is correct only.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    strat = System.currentTimeMillis();
    data = myDb.makeanswers(levels, Qno);
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.bsubmit:
        if (r0.isChecked() == true)

        {
            if (r0.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(data)) {
                showAnswer.setText("your answer is correct:" +r0.getText());

            } else {
                showAnswer.setText("your answer is wrong.the answer is:"
                        + data);

            }
        }
        if (r1.isChecked() == true)

        {
            if (r1.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(data)) {
                showAnswer.setText("your answer is correct:" + r1.getText());

            } else {
                showAnswer.setText("your answer is wrong.the answer is:"
                        + data);

            }

        }
        if (r2.isChecked() == true)

        {
            if (r2.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(data)) {
                showAnswer.setText("your answer is correct:" + r2.getText());

            } else {
                showAnswer.setText("your answer is wrong.the answer is:"
                        + data);

            }

        }
        if (r3.isChecked() == true)

        {
            if (r3.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(data)) {
                showAnswer.setText("your answer is correct:" + r3.getText());

            } else {
                showAnswer.setText("your answer is wrong.the answer is:"
                        + data);

            }
        }}}
```

plz help me out of it i am new to the android .it will be a great help

thanks,
maddy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try to do like this

```
case R.id.save_profile:
        if(((RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio0)).isChecked()){
            Answer=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio0)).getText().toString();
        }
       if(((RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio1)).isChecked()){
            Answer=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio0)).getText().toString();
       }  

        // compare here your option......


break;
```

after that you need to compare the answer with checked button.

Comment: you can take it as a String type

Comment: well i tried String type but it is giving an error as cannot covert from radiobutton to string

Comment: plz re check ur code  .it will be very help full i get the code going well

Comment: oooo thank u man.really it is very help full.i just putt trim() it is working fine.thank u bro

Answer (score 0):

your code is perfect. it works for me. Just check if your database retrievals and method makeanswer() are correct.

Comment: well i checked the makeanswer() method and try to show data into some other view. the problem is it is checking only the first radio button code if the answer is correct .for the first radio if the answer is wrong then it is executing the ELSE that is ok. for the other radios it is either write or wrong it is executing ELSE Statement that is what my problem

Answer (score 0):

```
   rb1=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rb1);
   rb2=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rb2);
   rb3=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rb3);
   rb4=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rb4);

rb1.setText("");//get from database options  
rb2.setText("");//get from database options  
rb3.setText("");//get from database options  
rb4.setText("");//get from database options  


//***********onclick of submit button{

int rd1=r_group.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            String textt = "" ;
/************for error if not click on radio btn**********************/
            if(rd1==-1)

            {
                {   
                AlertDialog ad=new AlertDialog.Builder(Mind_Boost_First.this).create();
                ad.setTitle("error");
                ad.setMessage("plz select any radio button");
                ad.setIcon(R.drawable.cross);
                ad.setButton("ok",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }
                });
                ad.show();
                }}  
/****************************** get radio checked to textt**************************/
            else
            {

                switch(rd1)
                {
                    case R.id.rb1:
                textt =rb1.getText().toString().trim();
                        Log.e("rrrrrrrrbbbbbbbb11111111",""+rb1.getText().toString().trim());
                        break;
                    case R.id.rb2:
                textt = rb2.getText().toString().trim();
                        Log.e("rrrrrrrrbbbbbbbb222222222",""+rb1.getText().toString().trim());
                        break;
                    case R.id.rb3:
                textt = rb3.getText().toString();
                        Log.e("rrrrrrrrbbbbbbbb3333333333",""+rb1.getText().toString().trim());
                        break;
                    case R.id.rb4:
                textt = rb4.getText().toString();
                        Log.e("rrrrrrrrbbbbbbbb4444444444",""+rb1.getText().toString().trim());
                        break;
                  }


/*get correct value in str*/

                String str=c.getString(6).trim();

                r_group.clearCheck();




                /*reset value of lable */
```

This is my snippet of code that works perfect for me