# need help in getting and putting data from RadioGroup

Tags: android

```
rGroup = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
    rGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            Toast.makeText(cont, checkedId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

in these code above, i'm trying to get what the user clicks on the radio group,

i shouldn't use onClicklistener right?

Comment: You can get your answer here  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8815129/radio-buttons-showing-only-first-option-correct-and-the-others-showing-all-wrong/8815310#8815310  
Hope it works for you..  :-)

Answer (score 0):

You get checkedId as parameter. This is the the id of the checked radio button. You can pass this value to findViewById to get the RadioButton object.